# Oracle v19: can ongoing transactions block concurrent deletes on involved tables for extended periods?

Tags: oracle

We have a severe issue with threads hanging in operations to an Oracle DB (v19, connected to via JDBC connections).

The situation frequently happens while our application runs a big transaction within which it does a lot of major (i.e. quite complicated, lots of joins, etc.) queries and then updates a bunch of rows. These transactions can take several minutes.

As we were able to analyze so far the transaction processing blocks other concurrent tasks when they try to delete individual entries from tables that are involved in said transaction. Concurrent selects and also updates to these same tables work fine! It's only **deletes** that have issues! And, as we were able to "proof", this happens even for deletes of individual entries that for sure *do not* interfere with or touch on any entry involved in the ongoing transaction.

While we first suspected Hibernate to interfere and do funny things for deletions we had to learn that even deletes executed via SQLDeveloper (i.e. triggered "manually" by a completely unrelated DB session and client) do hang during such periods.

To us it almost seems as if an ongoing transaction does not only lock specific rows from manipulation but locks *entire* tables.
But can that really be that a transaction block entire tables from concurrent delete operations for extended periods?

We think that would be absurd but - as we had to learn and can easily reproduce - deleting entries from tables touched by our long-running transaction invariably hang. Several times we also witnessed that - as soon as the transaction finishes - those deletes that haven't timed out, yet, continue and run to completion.

We are not aware of doing anything weird or unusual in our Hibernate-based application. We certainly don't fiddle with any locking mechanism or such. Any idea or hint what could cause these hangs and/or in which direction to investigate further to resolve this?

Later addition:

We are currently considering the following work-around: we add a column to these tables where we mark entries as being "to-be-deleted" (instead of actually deleting them as we do now). We then run a regular job  during times (e.g. nightly) which actually deletes these entries. We "only" need to make sure that no transaction is ever executed on these tables while that delete-job runs.
I really hate that approach, esp. since it will require to add another condition to many queries to exclude those "virtually deleted" entries but we have no better idea so far.

Comment: Do you have referential integrity constraints defined between the tables in question, such as ON DELETE ...  What about triggers?

Comment: Nope. No triggers, no functions, 2 stored procedures (but these are unrelated and are only used by two scripts that we occasionally run). There are no specific ON DELETE constraints, just a few constraints on foreign keys that may not be null. We also have indices on these foreign key columns. DELETE_RULE is "NO ACTION" everywhere.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys which these tables reference? Are the foreign key columns indexed?

Comment: As I wrote: yes, both.

Comment: @mmo Do the tables have any bitmap indexes? Because of the way bitmap indexes are compressed, they don't work well with concurrent DML and can cause excessive locking.

Comment: @ APC This turned out to be the issue, indeed. We had foreign key columns that had no indexes. As we had to learn (also from other sources) Oracle indeed locks the *entire* referenced table before doing deletes. Since we had not only one but several such columns in some of our tables this essentially blocked the *entire DB* causing our issues. In contrast to what I thought we had a couple of columns that had no indexes. We added these indexes by now and that seems to have solved the issue. Thanks!